# Also is there any way to create a gym environment that can be used without registering?

Tags: gym

Please see the title: is there any way to create a gym environment that can be used without registering?

To be specific, since we have already created the environment class, is there any way to directly call `gym.make` on the environment class, without registering the gym environment?